# How do I add a new line under a font.DrawText line?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this code:

```
if (this.FPS.GetFPS() >= 1)
    font.DrawText(null, String.Format("{0:N0} fps", this.FPS.GetFPS()), 5, 5, SharpDX.Color.Red);
```

I want to add another font.DrawText to be display under the first one for example something like this:

```
if (this.FPS.GetFPS() >= 1)
{
   font.DrawText(null, String.Format("{0:N0} fps", this.FPS.GetFPS()), 5, 5, SharpDX.Color.Red);
   font.DrawText(null, String.Format("{0:N0} time", DateTime.Now.ToString()), 5, 5, SharpDX.Color.Red);
}
```

But the second `font.DrawText` should be under the first one not to replace it.
So i tried in the first one to add newline:

```
font.DrawText(null, String.Format("{0:N0} fps", this.FPS.GetFPS()), 5, 5, SharpDX.Color.Red)+ Environment.NewLine;
```

But I get error:

> Error 1   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

How do I make two `font.DrawText` lines that will be one under the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to add a New Line to the font.DrawText function.  Instead, add the new line to your String.Format() instead.

```C#
font.DrawText(null, String.Format("{0:N0} fps \n {1}",
    this.FPS.GetFPS(),
    DateTime.Now.ToString()), 5, 5, SharpDX.Color.Red);
```

Your

{0} = this.FPS.GetFPS()
{1} = DateTime.Now.ToString()

you can keep adding as many arguments as you want but you need to define them